# Bat file that takes specific variables on specific lines from texts

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a batch file that searches through 2 texts. Captures a line of text in a variable (that contains at least one of 3 strings, but doesn't contain forth string) and its line number.
Searches through the second text and captures in another variable the line of text that exists on the line-number of the first variable.

I need to use the two lines-of-text (variable) after that as well.
I kind of managed through the first text reading, but not sure what I'm doing wrong in the second one:

```
@echo off
set "found="
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%a in (' find /n /v "" ^< "%LocalDir%\list.txt" ') do (
    echo "%%b"|findstr /i /c:"one two small" /c:"one two birds" /c:"one two strings" >nul && set found=1
    if defined found echo "%%b"|findstr /v /c:"one two small red apples" >nul || set "found="
    if defined found (
        echo %%a found
        @echo off & setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set var=%%b
        set Line_num=%%a
        endlocal
    ) else ( 
        echo %%a NOT FOUND
    )
    set "found="
)

REM part2--------------------

for /f "delims=" %%d in (list1.txt) do (
    set FullVersion=%%d
    @echo off & setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%e in ("%%d") do (
        if !Line_num!==%%e
        set var2=!FullVersion!
        echo !var2! 
    )
)

endlocal

echo %var%
echo %var2%
```

### Any help will be appreciated.

here is what I end up with as solution:

```
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%a in (' find /n /v "" ^< "%LocalDir%\software_list.txt" ') do (

echo "%%b"|findstr /i /c:"Micro Focus Enterprise " /c:"Micro Focus Visual" /c:"Micro Focus COBOL" >nul && set found=1

if defined found echo "%%b"|findstr /v /c:"Micro Focus Enterprise Server for .NET" >nul || set "found="
 if defined found (set LineNumber=%%a&set ProductName=%%b)
REM  else (echo Main Micro Focus product NOT FOUND. Nothing to do. Exit.&exit /b)
 set "found="
)


find "2." temp1.txt > temp3.txt
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims==" %%c in (temp3.txt) do (echo %%c >> %LocalDir%\software_list1.txt)
for /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a in (' find /n /v "" ^< "software_list1.txt" ') do IF %%a==%LineNumber% SET ProductVersion=%%b 

REM ECHO %LineNumber%
REM ECHO %ProductName%
REM ECHO %ProductVersion%

set ProductName=%ProductName:"=%
set ProductName=%ProductName: =%
set ProductVersion=%ProductVersion:"=%
set ProductVersion=%ProductVersion: =%




set out_file_name=%ProductName%_%ProductVersion%_%COMPUTER_NAME%
REM echo %out_file_name:"=%
```

Thanks a lot to everyone.

Comment: You should show _minimal_ contents of `list.txt` and `list1.txt`

Comment: What should the part2 do? You read a complete line, and compare it with `line_num`, if that match you echo the fullline (which must be the line_num).

Comment: More info here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4634

Comment: here is what I end up with as solution:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "found="
for /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a in (
  ' find /n /v "one two small red apples" ^< "%LocalDir%\list.txt" ') do (
 echo "%%b"|findstr /i /c:"one two small" /c:"one two birds" /c:"one two strings" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET lnbr=%%a&SET ltext=%%b
)

for /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a in (' find /n /v "" ^< "list1.txt" ') do IF %%a==%lnbr% SET L1txt=%%b 

ECHO(line number %lnbr%
ECHO(from LIST   %ltext%
ECHO(from LIST1  %L1txt%
```

This should do what you want - if I understand correctly. Much better to show your data and an example of required output. Trying to fix code that DOESN'T do something undefined is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I see some problems in your code:
This block makes no sense, as it set variables in a new setlocal context and after the endlocal the variables are lost.

> ```
>     @echo off & setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>     set var=%%b
>     set Line_num=%%a
>     endlocal
> ```

In the second block you open a setlocal context for each iteration, that will result in a overflow error.
And the endlocal after the Part2 seems also to be contraproductive.

The line `if !Line_num!==%%e` creates always a syntax error

Btw. Why do you use `@echo off` inside your code? The frist one at the batch start should be enough.

You should only use one `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning of the script.
You should only use DelayedExpansion toggling, if you have problems with exclamation marks.
You could use some echo's to see what happens, like

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%e in ("%%d") do (
    echo Compare: !Line_num!==%%e
    if !Line_num!==%%e set var2=!FullVersion!
    echo !var2! 
)
```

Comment: yes... you are right. I'm a bit of a Jeday into this :) so I'm not surprised I write crappy code

Comment: Added one more bug and some tips

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It all made sense. Will do some modification.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

rem I need to create a batch file that searches through 2 text FILEs.
rem Captures a line of text in a variable (that contains at least one of 3
rem strings, but doesn't contain forth string) and its line number.

set Line_num=
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (
       'findstr /N /I /C:"one two small" /C:"one two birds" /C:"one two strings" "%LocalDir%\list.txt"
     ^| findstr /V /C:"one two small red apples"' ) do (

   echo %%a found
   set var=%%b
   set Line_num=%%a
)

REM part2--------------------

if defined Line_num (

   rem Searches through the second text and captures in another variable 
   rem the line of text that exists on the line-number of the first variable.

   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%d in ('findstr /N "^" list1.txt') do (
      if %Line_num% == %%d (
         set var2=%%e
         echo %%e
      )
   )
)

echo %var%
echo %var2%
```